# Usin Preg_match_all with "\" character

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I am trying to get a expression from a string using `preg_match_all`

but it doesn´t work correctly I try this:

```
$string='this is a test hello \1234';
preg_match_all('[(\\)(0-9)], $string, $output);
```

It only shows "hello" if I quit the "\" of the $string I can see "hello 1234" but with "\" It doesn´t works.

Comment: So you want `\1234` right?

Comment: I want "hello \1234" the $string contains a long string but I simplify for this example

Comment: in your code you are missing the ending ' at the end of regexp.
also you need to use a character for start/end of regexp
for example /

Comment: Please read this first : https://regexone.com/ - Learn Regular Expressions with simple, interactive exercises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think i might have a solution for you

```
$string='this is a test hello \1234';
preg_match("/hello \\\\[0-9]*/", $string, $output);
var_dump($output);
```

the thing here are the 4 backslashes. I'm not 100% sure about this but i think it is because in php you need to escape backslash so `\\` produces `\`
and in the regular expression you need two backslashes as well (see praveen kumars answer for a good regexp explanation). So when you are using 4 backslashes, php changes that to 2 and that is what you need for this regexp

EDIT:
turns out there was some truth in my thoughts. check out [this](http://www.developwebsites.net/match-backslash-preg_match-php/) article for more explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you use something like this:

```
/^(hello \\[0-9]*)$/g
```

This will give you the whole one. See the `(` and `[` variations.

**Explanation**

[image: explanation]

Comment: I need that it works always that the string contains "\" the position can be different